# "Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>" Error when trying to remotely access jupyter notebook through a university system

Tags: python, terminal, jupyter-notebook

I am running a jupyter notebook using my uni computer using this technique - https://techtalktone.wordpress.com/2017/03/28/running-jupyter-notebooks-on-a-remote-server-via-ssh/ 
I use

> ssh -L 8000:localhost:8888 me@my_uni

When enter the command 'jupyter notebook' which would usually create a token, I instead get an error message:

> Could not find platform independent libraries
>
> Could not find platform dependent libraries
>
> Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to [:]
>
> Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
>
> Current thread 0x00007f11111f6740 (most recent call first):
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

When I do

> jupyter notebooker -version

I get the same error message.

I do not have a huge number of permissions on the university server. I know beggars can't be choosers but solutions which avoid needing those permissions would be great.

Any help would be fantastic, thank you!